# c# 5 await/async pattern in API design

Tags: c#

How can the c# 5 await/async pattern boost the expressiveness of new APIs that deals with coroutines (as Jon Skeet shows in recent posts), or with the actor model?

Comment: @dthorpe: I'm guessing that's supposed to be "How"

Answer (score 3):

As you mentioned, [Jon Skeet's has been discussing Coroutines using the Async CTP](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/06/22/eduasync-part-13-first-look-at-coroutines-with-async.aspx), so I will skip that portion of your question...

The actor model is actually being addressed in the Async CTP via [TPL Dataflow](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=14782).  This is a new library using the `Task` classes which allows for a form of the Actor model as well as many other data flow and similar scenarios.  Since it's based around the `Task` and `Task<T>` classes, it also integrates perfectly with `await`/`async` very nicely.