# Write a well designed async / non-async API

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I'm facing the problem of designing methods that with performs network I/O (for a reusable library). I've read this question

[c# 5 await/async pattern in API design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6528517/c-sharp-5-await-async-pattern-in-api-design)

and also other ones closer to my issue.

So, the question is, if I want provide **both async and non-async** method how I've to design these?

For example to expose a non-async version of a method, I need to do something like

```
public void DoSomething() {
  DoSomethingAsync(CancellationToken.None).Wait();
}
```

and I feel it's not a great design. I'd like a suggestion (for example) on how to define private methods that can be wrapped in public ones to provide both versions.

Comment: Important question: how is the async part of `DoSomethingAsync` implemented? This is important because if that is creating a `Task` and a worker thread, then the answer might be very different to, say, if you are using an external eventing API. Specifically, there's no point in having a the "sync" method call the "async" method and "wait", if the "async" method is taking a thread: it would be better to do the work directly. However, this changes for other meanings of "async" (not all "async" means "threads")

Comment: @MarcGravell, I'm trying to explain better (and it's not simple due English is not my primary language). I've "operation XYZ" that do intense I/O. I want to expose it in a library with two methods: one that returns almost immediately using an asynchronous pattern (as described in _MS Task-based Asynchronous Pattern doc_) and one that executes synchronous. What is the more **efficient** / **maintainable** / **unit-test enabled** way to this. A private method exposed with a public async wrapper and another sync wrapper, e.g.? If yes, how do this methods look like?

Comment: "efficient" and "maintainable" are not the same thing, and often disagree with each-other. And again: it all depends on how your "async" code is currently working. If that is procedural / linear code that you are just running on a separate thread, then frankly there's no point exposing it via "async". If that code is fully async, then it may be best to have 2 completely separate implementations, if you want "efficient" as a goal. Sorry, but this question is **hugely** context specific, and you haven't given much context.

Comment: @MarcGravell, yes to be honest the pair efficient+maintainable was an innocent _provocation_ to stimulate and extend the conversation without ending in an off-topic comment (I hope). My difficulty to reply to your question about how `DoSomethingAsync` is implemented is that I've actually only a sync stub and I'm open to rewriting all from ground up. As I suspected it depends all from complexity of the specific operation, unfortunately each case must evaluated alone and there's no common _pattern_ to rely on.

Comment: upvoted for burning my brain

Answer (score 77, accepted):

If you want the most maintainable option, only provide an `async` API, which is implemented without making any blocking calls or using any thread pool threads.

If you really want to have both `async` and synchronous APIs, then you'll encounter a maintainability problem. You really need to implement it twice: once `async` and once synchronous. Both of those methods will look nearly identical so the initial implementation is easy, but you will end up with two separate nearly-identical methods so maintenance is problematic.

In particular, there's a no good and simple way to just make an `async` or synchronous "wrapper". Stephen Toub has the best info on the subject:

1. [Should I expose asynchronous wrappers for synchronous methods?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/)
2. [Should I expose synchronous wrappers for asynchronous methods?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-synchronous-wrappers-for-asynchronous-methods/)

(the short answer to both questions is "no")

However, there are some hacks you can use if you want to avoid the duplicated implementation; the best one is usually the [boolean argument hack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2015/july/async-programming-brownfield-async-development#the-flag-argument-hack).

Comment: {+1} This was the thing I _needed_ to hear! In the meantime I'm ended up rewriting the methods to be truly async and not caring anymore about sync version. After all consumers could call DoSomethingAsync.Wait() **from their code** if they want to do it. I was concerned with Mono compatibility, but profile 3.0 supports `async`/`await` keywords, so the problem doesn't exists. By the way, great articles.

Comment: @jay I'll go further than +1; I'm currently sat in a session with Stephen Toub, and this answer is an ideal answer to a very complex question. So I'm going all-out with a +500.

Comment: @MarcGravell: Thanks! They wouldn't happen to be recording Stephen's session, would they? :)  I hardly ever get over to that side of the country...

Comment: @Stephen I dont think so, but none of it is NDA and so they (Stephen Toub and Lucian Wischik) have (it was asked) agreed to both: make the slide deck available, and blog some of what was covered (although much is already blogged)

Comment: I'd like to add one thing. Stated that one should not wrap `sync` method in an  `async` method (or the reverse) when designing a new API. I think that an acceptable compromise could be (1) factor code into small reusable types, (2) create both version trying to reduce repetitions but actually supplying two different implementations. This should be done if it make sense and if it's really necessary, I guess. There's no a specific pattern, but each case must be evaluated individually. And off course, all said before (for me) is confirmed.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with both Marc and Stephen (Cleary).

(BTW, I started to write this as a comment to Stephen's answer, but it turned out to be too long; let me know if it is OK to write this as an answer or not, and feel free to take bits from it and add it to Stephen's answer, in the spirit of "providing the one best answer").

It really "depends": like Marc said, it is important to know how DoSomethingAsync is asynchronous. We all agree that there is no point in having a the "sync" method call the "async" method and "wait": this can be done in user code. The only advantage of having a separate method is to have actual performance gains, to have an implementation which is, under the hood, different and tailored to the synchronous scenario. This is especially true if the "async" method is creating a thread (or taking it from a threadpool): you end up with something that underneath uses two "control flows", while "promising" with its synchronous looks to be executed in the callers' context. This may even have concurrency issues, depending on the implementation.

Also in other cases, like the intensive I/O that the OP is mentioning, it may be worth having two different implementation. Most operating systems (Windows for sure) have for I/O different mechanisms tailored to the two scenarios: for example, async execution of and I/O operation takes great advantages from OS level mechanisms like I/O completion ports, which add a little overhead (not significant, but not null) in the kernel (after all, they have to do bookkeeping, dispatch, etc.), and more direct implementation for synchronous operations. 
Code complexity also varies a lot, especially in functions where multiple operations are done/coordinated.

What I would do is:

- have some examples/test for typical usage and scenarios
- see which API variant is used, where, and measure. Measure also difference in performance between a "pure sync" variant and "sync". (not for the whole API, but for selected few typical cases)
- based on measurement, decide if the added cost is worth it.

This mainly because two goals are somehow in contrast with one another. If you want maintainable code, the obvious choice is implementing sync in terms of async/wait (or the other way around) (or, even better, provide only the async variant and let the user do "wait"); if you want performance you should implement the two functions differently, to exploit different underlying mechanisms (from the framework or from the OS). I think that it should not make difference from a unit-testing point of view how you actually implement your API.

Comment: There is a slight overhead to asynchronous programming, but it's all in the user-mode side. The Windows kernel is 100% asynchronous; there are no synchronous calls at the device driver level.

Comment: {+1} @dema80 your answer ad interesting OS considerations. I'd also like to hear what happens at low level in *nix/Mono (for intensive I/O). Another thing that could be added is relative to my last comment. Can the code be factored and then reused to have two really different implementations? Without wrapping and as you said addressing both versions. This is not all-day-programming but rather a framework design question. After all BCL has a lot of API with sync/async version side by side.

Comment: @StephenCleary of course, no modern kernel will block synchronously: and after, at low level, I/O is an asynchronous job (interrupts, IPCs, ...). This is not what I meant, I just pointed out that implementation for synchronous functions is likely to be more direct: I'm not sure about happening all in user-mode: I think that with synchronous I/O the thread builds the IRP, store it in the device stack, and waits in the kernel for the IRP to complete. With asynchronous I/O, APC or additional queuing is necessary. But then, I worked on this stuff in the Windows 2000 era, things might have changed!

Comment: @jay I am pretty confident when talking about windows internals, but I am not about Unix (and remember that low-level stuff varies a lot between flavors). As for your other question, I also was wondering how it would be possible to increase reuse; as for the BCL, my guess is that underlying it just calls the equivalent Win32 functions (after all, the win32 API already have implementations for async/sync I/O, which in turn uses different functions implemented in the NT kernel).

Comment: @dema80, agree with the point of win32 API and, as you said, it could be interesting investigate managed code reuse in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem but managed to find a compromise between efficiency and maintainability using two simple facts about async methods:

- asynchronous method which does not execute any await is synchronous;
- asynchronous method which awaits only synchronous methods is synchronous.

This is better to be shown on example:

```
//Simple synchronous methods that starts third party component, waits for a second and gets result.
public ThirdPartyResult Execute(ThirdPartyOptions options)
{
    ThirdPartyComponent.Start(options);
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    return ThirdPartyComponent.GetResult();
}
```

To provide maintainable sync/async version of this method it has been split to three layers:

```
//Lower level - parts that work differently for sync/async version.
//When isAsync is false there are no await operators and method is running synchronously.
private static async Task Wait(bool isAsync, int milliseconds)
{
    if (isAsync)
    {
        await Task.Delay(milliseconds);
    }
    else
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(milliseconds);
    }
}

//Middle level - the main algorithm.
//When isAsync is false the only awaited method is running synchronously,
//so the whole algorithm is running synchronously.
private async Task<ThirdPartyResult> Execute(bool isAsync, ThirdPartyOptions options)
{
    ThirdPartyComponent.Start(options);
    await Wait(isAsync, 1000);
    return ThirdPartyComponent.GetResult();
}

//Upper level - public synchronous API.
//Internal method runs synchronously and will be already finished when Result property is accessed.
public ThirdPartyResult ExecuteSync(ThirdPartyOptions options)
{
    return Execute(false, options).Result;
}

//Upper level - public asynchronous API.
public async Task<ThirdPartyResult> ExecuteAsync(ThirdPartyOptions options)
{
    return await Execute(true, options);
}
```

The main advantage here is that middle level algorithm which is most likely to change is implemented only once so developer don't have to maintain two almost identical pieces of code.