# Proper way to make an async call

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

I have a situation where scalability is of utmost importance. I have an API endpoint which has to make a call to a 3rd party web service and it could take over 10 seconds to complete. What I'm concerned about is web requests stacking up on our server while waiting for the 3rd party requests to complete. I need to make sure that the requests to "StartJob" return immediately and the job actually runs in the background. What's the best way to do this?

```
// Client polls this endpoint to find out if job is complete
public ActionResult GetResults(int jobId)
{
    return Content(Job.GetById(jobId));
}

//Client kicks off job with this endpoint
public ActionResult StartJob()
{
    //Create a new job record
    var job = new Job();
    job.Save();

    //start the job on a background thread and let IIS return it's current thread immediately
    StartJob(); //????

    return Content(job.Id);
}

//The job consists of calling a 3rd party web service which could take 10+ seconds.
private void StartJob(long jobId)
{
   var client = new WebClient();
   var response = client.downloadString("http://some3rdparty.com/dostuff");

   var job = Job.GetById(jobId);
   job.isComplete = true;
   job.Save();
}
```

Comment: Note that Task is 4.0, not 4.5.  What version *are* you using?  Tasks are a *fantastic* tool, even without `await`.

Comment: The "the Task or async keyword jazz" definitely sounds like a good solution - please reconsider seeing if you can use it.  *MEANWHILE*... what *are* you using?  What are the best options you're considering?

Comment: @Micah So then you *can* use tasks, just not `await`.

Comment: "I'm using .Net 4.0".  Cool - then async tasks *are* an option for you :)!

Comment: So starting something in a background thread is easy.  There are several ways to do it, but what's key is how that needs to interact with the other non-background work.  Does this background task produce a result?  If so, what is it, and where is it used?  Does the caller need to do something when the asnyc operation finishes, or can it continue on?

Comment: First of all, I don't get why this is being down voted, that seems petty to me.

Comment: The caller doesn't need to do anything with the result. They will be polling the endpoint to find out if it's completed yet. When the 3rd party call is complete then the db just needs to be updated. Once that happens then the caller will stop polling because it will know the job is done.

Comment: @Micah Really?  You don't recognize the quality of the question?  It's horribly vague; there's not really and strong definition of what you're asking.  "Make my code asynchronous" is not sufficient in terms of requirements.  Second, you've pretty much just stated your (very poor) requirements and asked for a solution.  it shows no research, nor attempts at solving it yourself, no more specific problem in the context of a larger problem, etc.  I'd expect someone who's spent as much time on SO as you to realize this.

Comment: What I don't want to happen is to #1 tie up the web request thread and #2 have the web request get killed and cause inadvertant side-effects because the 3rd party request is not properly running on a different thread or something weird.

Comment: @Micah Just throw all of `StartJob` into a new thread and be done with it if you want the fastest solution.  You can use less server resources by actually doing async IO rather than blocking IO, which is at least a tiny bit less trivial than that.

Comment: @Micah And what reserach have to done into investigating the various options and which may or may not apply to your particular case?  Also note that's not stated at all in your question.  You asked for how to execute the code asynchronously, not which threading framework to use.  If you had, it would be a Not Constructive question and should be closed.  Again, I'd have expected someone with as much experience with the site as you to know all of this.

Comment: @Micah even if the question is different you get valuable information on async topic form this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14870478/write-a-well-designed-async-non-async-api); if you wish to evaluate an alternative way for reference I suggest you what [RX](http://rx.codeplex.com) and [RXX](http://rxx.codeplex.com/) can do when join the forces with the async pattern, see [here](http://www.introtorx.com/) and in particular [here](http://www.introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/15_SchedulingAndThreading.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the caller doesn't care for the result you can do something like this:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(StartJob(job.Id));
```

You could also use this adaptation as suggested by Servy in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15441115/proper-way-to-make-an-async-call#comment21843379_15441262).

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(StartJob(job.Id), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
```

Comment: Because you're doing a long running operation in a thread pool thread.  That said, just tack on a `LongRunning` option and that'll solve that problem.

Comment: The "best way" is pretty subjective, but this is far and away the easiest way that meets the (assumed) requirement of "start a thing without blocking execution with no care for what happens to the thing I started."

Comment: You can also use Task<T> to get a result, and .ContinueWith() to act on that result.