# Maintain both synchronous and asynchronous implementations

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

What are the best practices to maintain both synchronous and asynchronous versions of the method?

```
Let's suppose we have the following method:
public ImportData Import(ZipFile zipFile)
{
  ... //Step 1. Initialization
  var extractedZipContent = zipFile.Extract(); //Step 2
  ... //Step 3. Some intermediate stuff
  var parsedData = ParseExtractedZipContent(extractedZipContent); //Step 4
  ... //Step 5. Some code afterwards
}
```

Step 2 and 4 a long-running so we want to call them asynchronously in asynchronous version of Import method:

```
public async Task<ImportData> ImportAsync(ZipFile zipFile)
{
  ... //Step 1. Initialization
  var extractedZipContent = await zipFile.Extract(); //Step 2
  ... //Step 3. Some intermediate stuff
  var parsedData = await ParseExtractedZipContentAsync(extractedZipContent); //Step 4
  ... //Step 5. Some code afterwards
}
```

Now we have both synchronous and asynchronous implementations. But we also have code duplication. How can we get rid of it?

We can extract Step 1, 3 and 5 and call them from both implementations. But 1. we still duplicate the order of methods calls 2. it is not so easy on real code

The best idea I came to is to have asynchronous implementation. And synchronous implementation would just wait for asynchronous implementation is finished:

```
public ImportData Import(ZipFile zipFile)
{
  var importAsyncTask = ImportAsync(zipFile);
  importAsyncTask.Wait();
  return importAsyncTask.Result;
}
```

But I am not sure about this solution. Are there any bestpractices regarding this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can we get rid of it?

You can't.

Stephen Toub has some excellent blog posts explaining the pitfalls of [synchronous wrappers for asynchronous methods](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-synchronous-wrappers-for-asynchronous-methods/) and [asynchronous wrappers for synchronous methods](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/). The short answer is: don't.

Your best bet is to maintain both for now. A few years from now the synchronous methods can be considered obsolete.

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14870478/write-a-well-designed-async-non-async-api).

Comment: +1 Interesting info Stephen.  Have not seen you in a while on the forums.  Good to see you active on SO.