# Intergrating both synchronous and asynchronous libraries

Tags: asynchronous, dart, synchronous, typed

Can synchronous and asynchronous functions be integrated into one call/interface whilst maintaining static typing? If possible, can it remain neutral with inheritance, i.e. not wrapping sync methods in async or vice versa (though this might be the best way).

I've been reading around and see it's generally recommending to keep these separate (http://www.tagwith.com/question_61011_pattern-for-writing-synchronous-and-asynchronous-methods-in-libraries-and-keepin and [Maintain both synchronous and asynchronous implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15507530/maintain-both-synchronous-and-asynchronous-implementations)). However, the reason I want to do this is I'm creating a behaviour tree framework for Dart language and am finding it hard to mix both sync and async 'nodes' together to iterate through. It seems these might need to be kept separate, meaning nodes that would suit a sync approach would have to be async, or the opposite, if they are to be within the same 'tree'.

I'm looking for a solution particularly for Dart lang, although I know this is firmly in the territory of general programming concepts. I'm open to this not being able to be achieved, but worth a shot.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: http://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2015/02/01/what-color-is-your-function/

Comment: That was a good read! Really interesting. So essentially what your saying is, don't use Dart, use Go instead? ;) Do you think sync functions will disappear?

Comment: Once some sort of "blocking" ability is added to Dart (see fletch), this will help break down the difference between sync and async. And yes, Go is more mature in this area. I look forward to seeing how fletch evolves.

Answer (score 1):

You can of course use sync and async functions together. What you can't do is go back to sync execution after a call of an async function.

Maintaining both sync and async methods is in my opinion mostly a waste of time. Sometimes sync versions are convenient to not to have to invoke an async call for some simple operation but in general Dart async is an integral part of Dart. If you want to use Dart you have to get used to it. 
With the new async/await feature you can write code that uses async functions almost the same as when only sync functions are used.

Comment: You have to get used to it, or wait for fletch ;)

Comment: Ah ok thanks. So the Dart-y way of doing it would be to favour async as a base class and (if desired) wrap sync method in an async one (purely to save some code time until await call, else I'd have to do competers separately in each node). Thanks. And Fletch?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Only functions are async not classes. In the Dart standard libraries some functions/methods are offered as async and additional sync variant `File.exists()` and `File.existsSync()`. The caller decides what he want's to use. What do you need async for anyway? As long as you don't use OS calls like file or network access or some other event driven model you probably don't need to use async at all.

Comment: In a nutshell fletch is a project to build an experimental Dart VM with new concurrency primitives. This will allow you to write code in a similar (but not identical) way as is done in Go with goroutines and channels. https://github.com/dart-lang/fletch/wiki/Coroutines-and-Threads

Comment: Yes, I know classes cannot be. To follow the Dart design pattern, I wanted the option for both sync and async functions in the library. I considered having a Node class with Future<bool> process() and bool processSync(), but the selectors and sequencers in the behaviour tree need to call the same function for each node (implementing the same interface), leading to individual classes & some fancy reflection on initialisation to tell apart the sync and future returning nodes. Async support is a library must (even for my own usage. I want to use it as the foundation of a server-side framework).