# How can I implement both an async method and its synchronous counterpart?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

I have a method such as `Task<string> GetContentAsync(string url)` and my **console application** is not quite ready to take advantage of the TPL internally, but maybe at a later date it will be.

How can I easily write a synchronous wrapper (not an alternative implementation) for this (or other) methods?

Comment: @Servy This has nothing to do with UI responsiveness and is thus not a duplicate of that question.

Comment: @MichaelJ.Gray It's true that it's not an *exact* duplicate, however the answer to that question answers this question, which makes it an appropriate use of the close functionality.

Comment: @Servy Considering that you need to get an implementation of some message pumping system in that answer, which does basically nothing useful in a console application, I would say it is inappropriately addressing the concern with an over engineered solution. There is no issue with continuation deadlocks in a console application by accessing `Task.Result`.

Comment: @MichaelJ.Gray 1) That's an extraordinarily useful tool, even in a console application.  In fact, if you read the article linked in that post the entire *reason* for creating it was a way of creating a synchronization context in a console application.  Next, while a console application, by default, won't have a sync context, and thus won't deadlock, you can *create* a sync context in a console application which could *make* this code deadlock, so console apps cannot ignore the issue entirely.

Comment: @Servy Except for the part where I set a context and it still works fine.

Comment: @MichaelJ.Gray Set something like a `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext`.  The `SynchroniationContext` class is mostly there to define the behavior; instances of it don't really do much on their own; it's the various inherited versions that do something useful.

Comment: @Servy Well, that would be a misuse of the context then. Basically you are saying "Do something unsupported in a very specific context." which in itself is bad advice. If someone was using that in a console application and they were complaining, the solution would be to move away from that specific context.

Comment: @MichaelJ.Gray That's simply an example that I can come up with without using a lot of code (being a comment, I cannot include much).  Another example would be using the `AsyncPump` that I reference in the proposed duplicate.  It creates as single threaded synchronization context.  If you used your method inside of a call to `AsyncPump.Run` it would deadlock.

Comment: @Servy Yeah well that still is misusing a construct. I will give you that it is in fact POSSIBLE to make a deadlock happen, but not with any reasonable or sane code. I suppose that if you were using properly defined functionality and your async code were deadlocking, it would be a bug in .NET. So, that's where I go with this. It won't deadlock unless you're intentionally causing it to do that or introduce a bug into your own code. But the essence here is not to introduce bugs or to say that without bugs the world is great. I just want a general wrapper. I think we have our solution already.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If your library needs to implement both synchronous and asynchronous members, then you implement both members. There are no shortcuts (assuming this is intended to be a reusable library).

```
public async Task<string> GetContentAsync(string url)
{
  ... // Logic here, e.g., using HttpClient
}

public string GetContent(string url)
{
  ... // Duplicate logic here, e.g., using WebClient
}
```

The duplication of logic is certainly unfortunate, but if you try to take shortcuts you'll actually end up in a worse situation. The details of "why" are a bit long for an SO answer, but Stephen Toub covers the problems that arise when wrapping in his classic pair of blog posts ["Should I expose synchronous wrappers for asynchronous methods?"](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-synchronous-wrappers-for-asynchronous-methods/) and ["Should I expose asynchronous wrappers for synchronous methods?"](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/)

BTW, the answer to both questions is "no". Also, see [my SO answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14876375/263693).

Comment: I read your answers and they looks pretty good but I wanted to write a wrapper for the other method, not a second implementation using synchronous method calls like you have with `HttpClient` for one and `WebClient` for the other. It's a little ambiguous I suppose, people may not read "wrapper" as explicitly a wrapper and it may suggest "an alternative implementation" depending on the person's thought process.

Comment: @MichaelJ.Gray: I know you want an easy wrapper. My point is that you can't have it. :)

Comment: I don't want an easy wrapper, I want a wrapper period. I don't want an alternative implementation. That's the nature of the question. It's very possible by using code generation to make a general solution for pretty much every case, even for non-async contexts. Though that is much more work than just making a wrapper for a method or putting together a pattern you can use to make wrappers. But I do say that your answer would satisfy this question if it were not strictly pertaining to making a wrapper and was just looking at getting the async functionality up and running.

Comment: @MichaelJ.Gray: I think code generation is a good future approach. I wouldn't say it's feasible right now, even for a large codebase, but perhaps after a couple versions of Roslyn (there's an [interesting project here](http://www.learnasync.net/) that is still under NDA at the moment). That said, I wouldn't consider code generation as a "wrapper".

Comment: That project looks amazing. A very good find.

Comment: Why not warp the common duplicated logic into a private method, and call from both places? Duplicated code is warranted to create problems in the long run.

Comment: @Alejandro: See the "bool argument hack" in [my article on brownfield async](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt238404.aspx).

Answer (score -2):

Here is the code for a test case showing that it's possible to do this in a very easy way. I also implemented a `GetContentAsync` method for demonstration purposes.

```
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AsyncTestCase.Driver
{
    public class AsyncTestCase
    {
        public AsyncTestCase()
        { }

        public string GetContent(string url)
        {
            Task<string> task = this.GetContentAsync(url);
            return task.Result;
        }

        public async Task<string> GetContentAsync(string url)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(url);
            HttpWebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync() as HttpWebResponse;

            using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    string content = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
                    return content;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is code to show that it works just fine and is easy to work with:

```
namespace AsyncTestCase.Driver
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            AsyncTestCase test = new AsyncTestCase();
            string content = test.GetContent("http://www.google.com");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is generally a very bad idea.  For a detailed explanation as to why see [Should I expose synchronous wrappers for asynchronous methods?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/13/10293638.aspx)

Comment: So, to whomever has downvoted. Could you provide information about how this answer is "not useful" please.

Comment: There is currently a comment on this answer explaining why this is a bad answer, and linking to an article that goes into great depth explaining the very serious problems that would result from the use of this answer.  That comment also has three upvotes, indicating several other readers feel that it is particularly relevant.  That comment was also posted well over an hour before your comment, so I would think that by now you'd have had ample opportunity to see it.

Comment: @Servy The answer is correct and thus useful to some. Just because you don't agree with the answer does not make it incorrect. The code compiles and functions as you would expect. You have also stated, with no descriptions, that it causes deadlocks. Can you demonstrate that or provide what you consider a useful answer?

Comment: The answer is not correct, does not function as you would expect, and while it may be useful to some, it is *very harmful* to suggest it's use given that a very large percentage of users would result in serious problems (namely, deadlocking their whole program) from its use.  I have linked you to multiple resources describing why the code deadlocks; it is too much information to adequately describe in comments; I attempted to do so, but apparently the summary was not sufficient for you.  Rather than me going into more depth, I suggest you *read the article explaining exactly why this is bad*.

Comment: But, can you prove it? You are basically asking us to take your word as gospel and keep bringing up unrelated UI things. This isn't for any kind of UI application, it is for a basic console application that has no synchronization context behavior. You have now gone so far as to downvote all of my answers relating to the topic and have downvoted others who have useful answers that you simply do not agree with. This is an abuse of the voting system, as the answers are useful in the context of the question.

Comment: I'm not asking you to take my word on anything.  I'm asking you to read the given article which *was written by the developers that wrote the entire `await` functionality for the language*.  It's probably a safe bet to take their word as gospel, but if you don't, consider reading the in depth explanation in which they describe exactly why this is a problem so that you don't *have* to take their word as gospel.

Comment: @Servy The reason I find difficulty in accepting this is because I cannot reproduce it in my console application, even with your `SynchronizationContext` remarks in the other comment chain.

Comment: "Just because you don't agree with the answer does not make it incorrect" - technically, the downvote is for "not useful" rather than "incorrect" but, in any case, people are free to vote as they wish - it's the SO 'swarm' that decides the overall value of answers by voting up or down. If Servey has decided it's not useful by his/her standards, you just have to hope others disagree. That's unlikely given the cited authorities, and something working in your environment doesn't make it correct, as evidenced by C's undefined behaviour as one example.

Comment: @MichaelJ.Gray, the reason mentioned in the article says that for .Result() call, you need another thread to execute the async call (in your example GetContentAsync()). The problem can arise in a situation where all those threads running async method are waiting for some other thread to pick up the result value, but if your ThreadPool is exhausted and no free threads are available then a deadlock occurs.

Comment: With await concept, your code doesn't have to create any new threads, given that the modern hardware can parallelize work just by utilizing their own cpus and accessing the memory in a DMA way, so after the async work is done, your origin thread will just be resumed, so I guess that's why it's considered a preferred way. I don't consider your answer wrong, it's just a bit unstable if you decide to limit your ThreadPool and/or expect a heavy traffic in your app.