# What is the best way to provide sync and asynchronous version on the same method?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, task

I have two methods in my repository `CountAsync (Expression <Func <TModel, bool> predicate)` and `Count (Expression <Func <TModel, bool >> predicate)`
i whant to implemente one and the second call the first implementation whats is the best way.

**1. I implement the async method**

```
    public Task<int> CountAsync(Expression<Func<TModel, bool>> predicate)
    {
        // some code;
        // .
        // .
        // .


        // call Entity Framework CountAsync method
        return _dbset.CountAsync(predicate);
    }
```

and then the second method

```
    public int Count(Expression<Func<TModel, bool>> predicate)
    {
        // calling the async version and get the result value
        return CountAsync(predicate).Result;
    }
```

**2. I Implement the sync method**

```
    public int Count(Expression<Func<TModel, bool>> predicate)
    {
        // some code;
        // .
        // .
        // .


        // call Entity Framework Count method
        return _dbset.Count(predicate);
    }
```

and then

```
    public Task<int> CountAsync(Expression<Func<TModel, bool>> predicate)
    {
        // embed the sync method in a task
        return Task.Run(() => Count(predicate));
    }
```

Comment: Implement two methods, [don't block on async code and don't wrap synchronous code with Task.Run](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html)

Comment: 3. In async method call `_db.CountAsync`, in sync method call `_db.Count`. Consumer of methods will decide what it needs to use.

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/14876375/3073551 answer, it does a pretty good job of explaining how to go / or not go about this

Comment: Why do you even want a synchronous version of that? You should always be calling the async version of Entity Framework methods

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto. Before introdution of Task we implement only the Sync versions of methods and The UI (Winform Or WPF) use these api via backgroundworker and so on to have asynchornous UI. untill now a lot of app relie on sync version on the api. after we introduce the async version for the new app we create. so wer still need the sync version of these method

Comment: In that case, I would highly suggest @Reniuz route. Leave the current code as is and implement the new asynchronous ones properly