# What is a safe way to wait synchronously with cancellation?

Tags: c#, .net, delay, deadlock, cancellation

I'm writing a .NET Standard 2.0 library that will have both synchronous and asynchronous versions of the same functionality, one of the features requires a delay with cancellation support.

I'm trying to come up with a way to wait a specific amount of time that would work without deadlocks or other gotchas in all scenarios. One worry is that [waiting synchronously on async methods can cause deadlocks](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

Consider this class, how should you implement `Wait` to make it safe anywhere? Calling `WaitAsync` is not a requirement, the wait could be implemented completely separately.

```cs
class Waiter
{
    // Easy enough
    public async Task WaitAsync(TimeSpan delay, CancellationToken token = default)
    {
        try
        {
            await Task.Delay(delay, token)
        }
        catch(OperationCancelledException)
        {
        }
    }

    // Not so straightforward
    public void Wait(TimeSpan delay, CancellationToken token = default)
    {
        WaitAsync(delay, token).GetAwaiter().GetResult(); // May deadlock
        WaitAsync(delay, token).Wait();                   // May deadlock, also doesn't propagate exceptions properly
        WaitAsync(delay).Wait(token);                     // Even worse
        Thread.Sleep(delay)                               // Doesn't support cancellation
        token.WaitHandle.WaitOne(delay, true);            // Maybe? Not sure how the second parameter works when I have no control over the context
        token.WaitHandle.WaitOne(delay, false);           // No idea
    }
}
```

Comment: I think if you configure the task not resume in the same context, then it is safe to wait synchronously. For example, ` var task = AwaitAsync(delay, token);
        task.ConfigureAwait(false);
        task.Wait();` However you may have thread sync issues if the code execution is not resumed in the captured context. Especially GUI applications does not allow the other  non GUI threads to modify the View

Comment: _"One worry is that waiting synchronously on async methods can cause deadlocks"_ -- yes, that's a worry. But, that doesn't mean _you_ should worry about it. Your API is either naturally async or synchronous; expose it in the natural way. Let the client worry about how to invoke it the other way. Your naturally synchronous API can be wrapped by the client with `Task.Run()` for example. Or your naturally async API can be blocked on by the client with a call to `Wait()` or `Result`, letting them worry about and address the hazards involved in doing so.

Comment: @MarcGravell Waiting on the async method is not a requirement, I just want to wait a specific amount of time. Method `Wait` doesn't have to call `WaitAsync`

Comment: BTW `token.WaitHandle.WaitOne` does not  block the thread till the task is finished. It blocks till the token is cancelled. If the token was not cancelled, but the task is finished, then `token.WaitHandle.WaiteOne` will lead to the deadlock. However, if the `CancellationTokenSource` is disposed from the other running threads, the blocked thread may resume

Comment: @zafar: the OP can clarify, but my understanding of that option is that they are relying on the `delay`, which times out the wait after some period of time. I.e. they are implemented the "wait" using the `delay`, and using the handle to signal cancellation.

Comment: _"that will have both synchronous and asynchronous versions of the same functionality"_ -- that's a fundamental mistake. See marked duplicate. If you want the more specific question about the wait answered, you'll need to post a more specific question. It's not even clear from your question whether you _literally_ want to wait some period, and if so why (what's the point of that?). And even if you do, since a wait handle is in fact the usual way to implement a block-the-thread wait with cancellation, you should have tried that and then explained why that didn't work for you.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14870478/write-a-well-designed-async-non-async-api) *almost* answers all your question. Specifically, it explains that implementing sync and async APIs by having one call the other is not a good idea. If you're in this situation, I recommend the [boolean argument hack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2015/july/async-programming-brownfield-async-development).

For your specific problem, ideally you would use a synchronous wait (`Thread.Sleep`), but since it doesn't support `CancellationToken` that's not an option. So you'd need to write it yourself. As noted in your question, `WaitHandle` has a timeout parameter which you can use:

```
public void Wait(TimeSpan delay, CancellationToken token = default)
{
  token.WaitHandle.WaitOne(delay);
}
```

It's worthwhile taking a look at how [Polly](http://www.thepollyproject.org/) handles this, and indeed, they implement their [synchronous cancelable delay](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/ffe99a34edd96d5c5c94075fe22aae8e1a7ed3ed/src/Polly/Utilities/SystemClock.cs#L18) in this way:

```
public static Action<TimeSpan, CancellationToken> Sleep = (timeSpan, cancellationToken) =>
{
  if (cancellationToken.WaitHandle.WaitOne(timeSpan))
    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
};
```