# How do I invoke DisposeAsync from a class finalizer?

Tags: c#, async-await

what do I do if I meet, for instance, following situation: my class is a wrapper around some third-party class and will have to invoke an async method from the wrapped class inside my Dispose? (see the code below).
Of course I will implement IAsyncDisposable.

But Microsoft [recommends](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose) disposables to be able to be disposed from their finalizers

And my question is how do I do it here?

In [the documentation example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-disposeasync#implement-both-dispose-and-async-dispose-patterns)  the async-disposable-only object (_asyncDisposableResource) is not disposed in case of disposal from finalizer, if it doesn't support IDisposable as well.

btw they say it's better not to support synchronous pairs for async method: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14876375/1438829) , so this situation is pretty likely.

```c#
    public class MyWrapperForTheRepository: IAsyncDisposable
    {
        private ThirdPartyRepository _wrappedRepository = new ThirdPartyRepository();

        public void MakeSomeChanges() => _wrappedRepository.MakeSomeChanges();


        public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
        {
            await _wrappedRepository.SaveAllTheChangesAsync();
            _wrappedRepository = null;
        }

        ~MyWrapperForTheRepository()
        {
            ?????????????????????
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where do you see such recommendation? What you have is fine.

Comment: Note: You should only dispose *unmanaged* resources from a finalizer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But Microsoft recommends disposables to be able to be disposed from their finalizers

Not at all. In fact, finalizers should *not* call (the parameterless) `Dispose()`, and they should *not* call `DisposeAsync()` either.

Finalizers are *only* for disposing unmanaged resources. Personally, I recommend that every type *either* have unmanaged resources *or* managed resources, and never both. The resulting code is much cleaner than following the `Dispose(bool disposing)` pattern.