Exposing Synchronous and Asynchronous versions of the same method
I have a method with the following method signature (.NET 8, C# 12):
public static async Task<Model> GetModelFromSchemaAsync (SqlConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    var model = new Model();
    using (var dataTable = await connection.GetSchemaAsync("MetaDataCollections", cancellationToken))
    { ... /* Logic */ ...}

    return (model);
}

I want to expose a synchronous  version of this method as follows:
public static Model GetModelFromSchema (SqlConnection connection)
{
    var model = new Model();
    using (var dataTable = connection.GetSchema("MetaDataCollections", cancellationToken))
    { ... /* Logic */ ...}

    return (model);
}

I often find the need to do this when writing libraries (albeit for my own consumption). I write my own code-generators so exposing both synchronous and asynchronous versions of such methods is important for my scenario. As the number of methods and their lines-of-code increase, so does duplication of logic.
I have seen examples of people taking the following approach:
public static Model GetModelFromSchema (SqlConnection connection)
{
    // The asynchronous method is being called synchronously (without `await`).
    var task = MsSqlServerAdoSchema.GetSchemaAsync (connection, CancellationToken.None);
    var model = task.GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    return (model);
}

There are two questions here:

Is the third method implemented correctly (to call the async version while blocking the current thread), or should I watch out for any gotchas!?
In addition to the second and third methods above, is there a better way to provide both synchronous and asynchronous versions of such methods without duplication of logic?



The 3rd implementation will block, YOU DON'T want this in UI apps, unit tests and stuff it's fine. 2. No because calling Async from sync and vice versa is not how it's done, except for scenarios like fire & forget. Unless you have clients that won't work with Async there's no reason to have sync IMHO.


@JeremyThompson: The intention of the synchronous implementation IS to block until task completion. Does the implementation look correct though? This is my first time trying to achieve this.

It can deadlock

Your questions are de facto answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343594/how-to-call-asynchronous-method-from-synchronous-method-in-c?rq=2

Stephen Cleary describes your pattern as The Blocking Hack, and it's insidious because it can appear to work in a unit test and then deadlock if it's in a UI or ASP.NET (not Core) application.

@DanielA.White it will deadlock only of the MsSqlServerAdoSchema.GetSchemaAsync is implemented with async-await, and includes at least one await not configured with .ConfigureAwait(false). Which is highly unlikely for any asynchronous API included in any decent library (library that is actively maintained, and owned/authored by devs who know what they are doing).

Would this be a better duplicate match? https://stackoverflow.com/q/14870478/120955

@TheodorZoulias: OP does not specify that MsSqlServerAdoSchema.GetSchemaAsync comes from such a library, and it sounds like they're looking for a general-purpose pattern to follow. They specifically asked for any "gotchas," so I think it's safe to call out that deadlocks are a real possibility from this pattern.

@StriplingWarrior sure, one could write an answer that, among others, mentions the possibility of a deadlock. My point is that this possibility is small, and its effects are usually exaggerated. Deadlocks of this kind tend to occur consistently and loudly (assuming that the conditions are met). It's highly unlikely to stay unnoticed during the development/debugging of the application. In the context of this question, I don't think that the possibility of deadlocks is the No 1 reason for avoiding sync over async. There are more compelling reasons than that.

@StriplingWarrior yes, the question Write a well designed async / non-async API looks like a reasonable duplicate, with at least one good answer.

Whoever downvoted this question should have realized that it took me the effort of posting this question to find the correct answer (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2015/july/async-programming-brownfield-async-development?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058#the-blocking-hack). Please be sensible so others who are looking for similar solutions can benefit.

@Raheel you could consider posting an answer to the duplicate question, and explaining why you think that doing sync over async (.GetAwaiter().GetResult()) is the correct answer to this problem. Personally I think that it's best to leave your code as is, using native synchronous APIs for your synchronous APIs, and native asynchronous APIs for your asynchronous APIs. So I would love to read your reasoning for thinking otherwise.

Related article: Should I expose synchronous wrappers for asynchronous methods?
